# Jquery Keyup Filter And Input Value Problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

I'm searching in the table with jquery. Searching with keyboard is working but filtering with button does not work
Please click to button.

I want it to be added to the input and search when the button is clicked

Sample:

```js
/* Searching with keyboard */
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#search").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("table td").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});

/*Searching with button */
$("button").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
    $("#search").val(id);
});
```

```css
table tr td{
  border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search"><br>
<button type="button" data-id=""> Facebook</button>
<button type="button" data-id=""> Facebook</button>
<p>Searching with keyboard is working but filtering with button does not work. <br>Please click to button.</p>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Hood 1</td>
            <td>Hood 2</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td> Facebook</td>
            <td> Facebook</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Twitter</td>
            <td> Twitter</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: added answer. You are missing call for search keyup function on button click. @Cihan-sulu

Comment: thank you its working :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing call for search keyup function on button click

```js
/* Searching with keyboard */
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#search").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("table td").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});

/*Searching with button */
$("button").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
    $("#search").val(id);
    $('#search').keyup();
    
});
```

```css
table tr td{
  border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search"><br>
<button type="button" data-id=""> Facebook</button>
<button type="button" data-id=""> Twitter</button>
<p>Searching with keyboard is working but filtering with button does not work. <br>Please click to button.</p>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Hood 1</td>
            <td>Hood 2</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td> Facebook</td>
            <td> Facebook</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Twitter</td>
            <td> Twitter</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Don’t forget to accept answer too @CihanSulu Thanks